# Sending kendo grid in form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to send data from grid using Html form.

My Model is similar to this:

```
    public class Exam
    {
            public int Id { get; set; }

            public string Name { get; set; }

            public int Duration { get; set; }

            public virtual List<Question> AvailableQuestions { get; set; }
    }

    public class Question 
    {
            public int Id { get; set; }

            public string Content { get; set; }

            public int Points { get; set; }
    }
```

Now, in my View I have form like this:

```
    @model Exam
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Exams", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)

        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Question>(Model.AvailableQuestions)
                    .Name("availableQuestionsGrid")
                    .Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.Bound(c => c.Id);
                        columns.Bound(c => c.Content);
                        columns.Bound(c => c.Points);
                        columns.Template(@<text>/text>).ClientTemplate(@"<a class=""k-button-icontext k-grid-edit"" href=""\#"">Edit</a> | <a class=""k-button-icontext k-grid-delete"" href=""\#"">Delete</a>").Width(100);
                    })
                    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
                    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Template(@"<a class='k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-add' href='/Exams/Add?grid-mode=insert'><span class='k-icon k-add'></span>Add</a>"))
                    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                        .Ajax()
                        .Batch(true)
                        .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Id))
                        .ServerOperation(false))
                        )


         <input type="submit" value="Save">
    }
```

When I enter some text, add some questions to grid and then click "Save" button I have my name field binded, but my AvailableQuestions list is always null.

Is it possible to pass data from grid to controller on form submitting?

Answer (score 0):

How to submit Kendo Grid models along with a form is demonstrated and explained here:

http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/submit-form-containing-grid-along-with-other-input-elements

The idea is that for each column you have to specify a template which has a hidden input that holds the value for that item.

Comment: Please carefully note the disadvantages listed on that code library page.  This technique will only really work for small, single page datasets and you will need to deal with *every* row, not just new/changed rows on the server.